# Nested patterns in tmLanguage.json - how to match first keyword occurrence only?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, tmlanguage

I'm confused how nested patterns work in tmLanguage.json
When I have the following code:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinring/tmlanguage/master/tmlanguage.json",
  "name": "myexample",
  "scopeName": "source.myexample",
  "patterns": [
    {
      "begin": "^(foo):",
      "end": "$",
      "beginCaptures": {
        "1" : {"name": "myfoo"}
      },
      "patterns": [
        {
          "match": "^(bar)",
          "captures": {
            "1" : {"name": "mybar"}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd expect it to match this text:

```
foo:bar:bar
```

and capture word `foo` and first `bar` but not the second `bar`
However, it only matches `foo` and nothing else.

If I remove `^` from `^(bar)` it matches both `bar`, but if I replace it with `:` it matches only second `bar`

**So how do I make sure it captures only first occurrence of `bar` in the line, but only if it follows after `foo:` or if it's at the beginning of the entire line?:**

```
foo:bar:bar -> should match
bar:bar -> should match
blah:bar:bar -> should not match
```

The `foo:` is optional it may or may not be present and I'd like to avoid duplicating the pattern with something like `^(?!foo:)bar`

As I understand from [TextMate](https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars) grammar manual that nested `patterns` will use text that matched between `begin` and `end` of it's parent `patterns`, which confuses me why using `^` doesn't work or `:` captures only second occurrence...

Answer (score 1):

`^` always matches at the [beginning of a line](https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/blob/master/doc/RE#L174).
Using `:` won't help either, because your first colon is already consumed by `^(foo):`.
Depending on your exact use case, you might instead check for a `:` following the relevant `bar`:

```json
"match": "(bar)(?=:)",
```

or check that it is not at line end:

```json
"match": "(bar)(?!$)",
```

To match a line reading `bar:bar`, you might have to put all rules on the top level, using `"match"` throughout.

In that case, the above part might be written as:

```json
"match": "(?<=^|foo:)(bar)",
```